# Scaling a variable at a specific ratio of the viewport

Tags: javascript, math, formula

When the viewport is at a 1:1 width-to-height ratio (e.g. 1000x1000 resolution), I want a variable to be set to 0.22.

When the viewport is at a 2:1 width-to-height ratio (e.g. 2000x1000 resolution), I want that variable to be 0.33.

This should **scale smoothly** both up and down to any resolution (e.g. 500x1000 is 0.11; 4000x1000 is 0.55, etc.) after a resize event. How could I go about accomplishing this?

```
window.addEventListener('resize', scaleViewport);

function scaleViewport() {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;

    // ...no idea how to write this formula...
}
```

Comment: You realise that the values you've provided are not being stepped ina a linear way? The jump from 0.5:1 to 1:1 is not the same as 1:1 to 2:1 ***but you still expect a linear output steps***...

Comment: @Pineda - I would assume OP is thinking about the proportional difference between the width and height dimensions, rather than the actual value.

Comment: @Pineda - OP does not mention linear, only smooth

Comment: so, how do you calculate this value ... why is 2:1 == 0.33, 1:1 == 0.22 and 1:2 == 0.11 - is there a formula you are using?

Comment: @JaromandaX: the OP doesn't mention linear, but the steps expected are linear: 0.11, 0.22, 0.33 for ratios 0.5, 1, 2 (the former being linear, the ratios being not)

Comment: given 3 points is not enough to determine the shape of the "curve" :p - if I gave you three points (-1,-1) (0,0) and (1,1) - would you know if the equation is `y = x^3` `y = x` :p

Comment: @fubar: If they were thinking of proportional, they didn't express it in the question.  They asked for smooth but then provided a value out of proportion.  I see your point though :)

Comment: So 4000x1000 should be 0.44?

Comment: @ManuelOtto 3000x1000 would be 0.44. Then 4000x1000 would be 0.55.

Comment: @JaromandaX My mistake on the confusion. I meant to imply that it would continue to scale (e.g. 3000x1000 would be 0.44; 4000x1000 would be 0.55, etc.).

Comment: well, that's a shame, thought I had your formula, but it seems it's not a very straight forward formula at all ... seems it `((ratio + 1) * 1.1)` for ration >=1 and something else for ratio < 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula seems to be

```
0.11 * (2 + Math.log2(w/h))
```

Internet Exploder does not have Math.log2

So, you'll need this polyfill from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2#Polyfill

```
Math.log2 = Math.log2 || function(x) {
  return Math.log(x) * Math.LOG2E;
};
```

```js
const formula = (w, h) => .11 * (2 + Math.log2(w/h));
console.log(formula(1000, 1000)); // should be 0.22
console.log(formula(2000, 1000)); // should be 0.33
console.log(formula(500, 1000));  // should be 0.11
// unfortunately that's where this formula ends being right
console.log(formula(3000, 1000));  // should be 0.44
console.log(formula(4000, 1000));  // should be 0.55
```

Given the new information about what 3000:1000 and 4000:1000 should be

```js
const formula = (w,h) => {
    if (w/h < 1) {
        return w/h * 0.22;
    } else {
        return (w/h + 1) * 0.11;
    }
};
console.log(formula(1000, 1000)); // should be 0.22
console.log(formula(2000, 1000)); // should be 0.33
console.log(formula(500, 1000));  // should be 0.11
console.log(formula(3000, 1000));  // should be 0.44
console.log(formula(4000, 1000));  // should be 0.55
```

Comment: You nailed it with the updated code. Very impressed with how quickly you got that. And holy cow, you even provided a polyfill for IE! If I had more upvotes, you would get them all.

Comment: the polyfill isn't required for the actual answer :p

Comment: But still! How many answers come with self-made polyfills? I'd wager not many. Thanks for everything, sir.

Comment: Polyfill isn't mine - it's from MDN - whenever I use a function in an answer that MAY be only available in newer browsers, I check MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2#Polyfill - I highly recommend MDN for javascript documentation needs :p